# TypeError: Input 'ref' of 'Assign' Op requires l-value input

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a beginner with TensorFlow so I am just trying to run the Fibonacci algorithm.

So far, I wrote this code:

```
a=tf.constant(1)
b=tf.Variable(1)
print(a)
print(b)

with tf.Session() as session:
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    session.run(init_op)
    for i in range(0, 10):
        sum_value = tf.add(a, b)
        assign_op1=tf.assign(a, b)
        assign_op2=tf.assign(b, sum_value)
        session.run(assign_op1)
        session.run(assign_op2)
        print(sum_value)
```

For it, I am getting this error message:

```
   Tensor("Const_11:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)

<tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x7f0d446cfbd0>

TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-25b7f828d7c6> in <module>()
     10     for i in range(0, 10):
     11         sum_value = tf.add(a, b)
---> 12         assign_op1=tf.assign(a, b)
     13         assign_op2=tf.assign(b, sum_value)
     14         session.run(assign_op1)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_state_ops.pyc in assign(ref, value, validate_shape, use_locking, name)
     38   return _op_def_lib.apply_op("Assign", ref=ref, value=value,
     39                               validate_shape=validate_shape,
---> 40                               use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
     41 
     42 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.pyc in apply_op(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    515             raise TypeError(
    516                 "Input '%s' of '%s' Op requires l-value input" %
--> 517                 (input_name, op_type_name))
    518           input_types.extend(types)
    519         else:

TypeError: Input 'ref' of 'Assign' Op requires l-value input
```

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line `tf.assign(a, b)` you are instructing Tensorflow to assign the value of `b` to the variable `a`. However, you declared `a` as a `tf.constant` in the first line -- and you can't assign a new value to a constant. As Tensorflow writes, the first argument to the `'Assign' Op` requires **l-value input**, or in other words, something that can be modified. A constant is not an l-value input, but rather an r-value input.

If you replace your first line with `a=tf.Variable(1)` then you have a program that will execute successfully.